# How do I know this npm package can bundle using bundler?

Tags: javascript, css, npm, package

There are lot of NPM packages are available and some packages have CDN links also. How do I know chosen npm package can bundle using bundler to get optimum output file for production? Some packages give same size output file which is available with CDN and not optimized. Bundlers can be vite, webpack etc.

I know react, solid, tailwind give optimum files using module bundler. But I don't know bootstrap, jQuary etc. can get optimum files using module bundler.

This question may be basic question but considering this can decide use CDN or NPM installation.